# Laravelのindexとは

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

プログラミング自体も初心者、laravelを学習し始めて二日目で、教本を片手に作業しています。
indexというのものの概念がよく分かりません。

打ち込み練習でも何度もでてきましたし、vendorのファイルなんかにもindexというファイルがいくつも存在します。

英単語でいうと「見出し」という意味が頭をよぎるのですが、関係ありますか？

```
Route::get('hello','HelloController@index');
public function index(){}
```

などです。

Comment: 単にindexといってもいくつもの意味で使われる言葉ですがどのあたりに使われてるものかを是非書き添えてください。（ところでWebプログラム自体初心者さんでしょうか）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文脈にもよりますが、静的なhtml/jsで言えば、
「あるURLをファイル名（foo.html）部分を省略して開いた時に、デフォルトで表示されるファイル」
です。

転じて、phpでも意味として似たような機能を提供するCのアクションやVを、
indexアクション（phpメソッド）と名前付けることが多いです。

例：
想定URLパスルーティングやマッピング：
ｈｔｔｐ://domain:port/ [controller≒機能] / [action≒操作または子機能] / [id]
作るべき画面や操作：
・最新表示または個別ページ表示
・新規ページ追加
・ページ編集
・ページ削除
[controller] = blog
[action] = index(read), new(create), edit(update), delete

Comment: なるほど、デフォルトのニュアンスのイメージは全くなかったので参考になります。ありがとうございます。